# Cannot print JSON array from ajax call using the array length

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

This is the Javascript with the Ajax call, everything is working fine, I don't need to parse JSon 'cause it already comes parsed and the object has an array inside. The problem is when I try to print the array output using the for loop into html, it does not recognize the "data.d.lenght" for some reason. I changed it for an Int to test and all the values were printed in HTML. I even used .done in case the Ajax call was being done after the javascript was running and it changed nothing. I don't know what else I can do besides getting a variable with the array size from codebehind but that is a last resort.

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
            function GetColaboradores() {

                var url = "GetColaboradoresWebService.asmx/GetColaboradores";

               $("#UpdatePanel").html("<div style='text-align:center; background-color:yellow; border:1px solid red; padding:3px; width:200px'>Please Wait...</div>");

                var request = $.ajax({
                    type: "POST",
                    url: url,
                    data: "{}",
                    contentType: "application/json; charset-utf-8",
                    dataType: "json"
                });



                request.done(function (data) {

                    var TableContent = "<table border='0'" +
                                            "<tr>" +
                                                "<td> Nome </td>" +
                                            "</tr>";
                    for (var i = 0; i > data.d.lenght; i++) {
                        TableContent += "<tr>" +
                                                "<td>" + data.d[i].Nome + "</td>"
                        "</tr>";
                    }
                    TableContent += "</table>";
                    $("#UpdatePanel").html(TableContent);
                });

                request.fail(function () {

                });
            }        
    </script>
```

Comment: `length`.  typo.  You mispelled it in the title, the question, and the code .....

Comment: I would edit the question to show the correct spelling of "length", however as per @Taplar 's comment, without reading further I believe this may be your error.

Comment: @JFC just fix your typo then tell us if those fixed codes work as expected.

Comment: I can't check right now, but tomorrow when i'm at work I will change this. I can't believe this was the mistake... but it makes sense. Thanks for the quick finding though, I'm not english so I completely overlooked it

Answer (score 0):

Thanks everyone, I finally found what was wrong. Not only length was written wrongly but also the condition on the for cycle was wrong. It was "<" and not ">".